# How to get from a list of a Monad to a Monad of a list

Tags: haskell, monads

I am looking for a way to convert a type of [m [a]] to m [[a]] where m is a Monad of some type.

Comment: How did you end up with an `[m [a]]` in the first place? Likely you can make use of another monadic function to prevent first producing a list of `m [a]`.

Comment: I'm mapping over an IO [a] array and get the [IO [a]]

Comment: If you have an `f :: a -> IO [b]` mapping, you can use `mapM f list` with `list :: [a]` the input.

Comment: Thank you I will try that out.

Comment: It works like you said thank you very much !! Now I don't even need the _sequence_ anymore and after applying _concat_ I get **IO [a]**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for [Control.Monad.sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence)

```
λ> import Control.Monad (sequence)

λ> sequence [Just [1,2,3], Just [4,5,6], Just [7,8,9]]
Just [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Its type is `(Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`.
Specialising `t` to `[]` and `a` to `[a]`, we get

```
sequence :: [m [a]] -> m [[a]]
```

Comment: Incidentally, with the simplified signature this is also [what Hoogle suggests immediately](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Bm+a%5D+-%3E+m+%5Ba%5D&scope=set%3Astackage).

Comment: For the curious: `traverse id [Just [1,2,3], Just [4,5,6], Just [7,8,9]]`

Comment: What does traverse do ?

Comment: `traverse` is a way to get from `[a]` to `[m b]` and `[m b]` to `m [b]` all in one step; it has a type of `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`. More generally, its signature is `traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`. It can be defined as `traverse f t = sequenceA (fmap f t) `. Normally, `sequenceA` (which is the applicative version of `sequence`) is defined as `traverse id`. A good tool to learn about new functions is [Hoogle](http://hoogle.haskell.org/)